# Can I merge multiple datasets using multiple keys in SAS hash merge?

Tags: hash, sas

Can I use SAS hash merge to merge three datasets by two keys.

For example, the lookup datasets DATA1 has column A and B. I would like to merge DATA1 and DATA2 by key A and merge DATA1 and DATA3 by key B. Can I do that in one step hash merge?

Comment: Your question is, 'is something possible'. What you're really asking is 'how do I merge multiple datasets...'. When asking a question it helps to be as clear as possible. Per SO rules you should post what you've tried and enough sample information that someone can run your code for testing to improve it. Right now, we'd have to generate our own sample data and then write the code and the more difficult you make it for someone to help you the less likely they are, and the longer you wait for an answer.

Comment: The lookup table1 has column A and B; There are two datasets DATA2 and DATA3. Data2 has column A and C, Data3 has column B and D. What I want to output has column A B C and D. My question is if I define two hash hash1 and hash2, can I write two set data1 and data2?

Comment: I'd say yes. But if you would take the time to edit your question, to add three sample datasets and the desired output, that would help people help you. Also show what code you have tried. For example, code up the hash merge of two tables, then try yourself to extend it to three.

Answer (score 1):

In a hash merge, you define the keys and relationships for each table.  You're free to have whatever key value relationships you like, and certainly can do more than one set of keys.

Comment: but how to set multiple tables that link to different hash tables?

Comment: Perhaps you should show some example data and code in your question?

Comment: The lookup table1 has column A and B; There are two datasets DATA2 and DATA3. Data2 has column A and C, Data3 has column B and D. What I want to output has column A B C and D. My question is if I define two hash hash1 and hash2, can I write two set data1 and data2?